# Where can I read reviews of mathematical theories?

Tags: soft-question, mathematics-education

I'm really enjoying the AMS column "What is ..." (http://arminstraub.com/math/what-is-column) and The Princeton Companion to Mathematics.

I am looking for something similar. I'd like to acquire some intuition behind different subjects and the general overview rather than digging into details and technical proofs.

I want to read more about the motivation, the greatest results and applications (inside and outside of mathematics).

Comment: As previous vague and broad big-list questions, this will soon be closed, then reopened, then closed again, then reopened again, ... for some random outcome.

Comment: I read through the Bulletin of the AMS, which is a mix of feature articles and book reviews.  It's higher level than is ideal for your purposes, but it has given me some idea what's happening in different areas.

Comment: I'll be interested in any answer to this question, but I do think it's far too broad for this specific site.

Comment: "The Princeton Companion to Mathematics" might be a good source for some such material.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On the popular level, there is an AMS feature column:
http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-current.cgi
and a series of 10 volumes "What's happening in mathematical sciences":
https://bookstore.ams.org/HAPPENING,
also by AMS.

On a higher level, there are journals which publish surveys, addressed to
the general audience of mathematicians: Bulletin of the AMS, Russian Math Surveys,
Sugaku expositions, Gazette des Mathematiciens, Expositiones Mathematicae, L’Enseignement Mathématique, and several other such journals.

Answer (score 4):

An addendum to Alexandre's answer: I have noticed that in some "proceedings"  or "conference" volumes, the first article (or the introduction) is a very nice overview of the theory that is treated in the book. The same can be found in books with the title "on the occasion of the [age]-th birthday of [some big name in mathematics]".

Answer (score 1):

Look for books with the word "Handbook" in the title.  These often contain well-written survey articles by leading experts.  The downside is that "Handbooks" tend to be rather expensive, but you may be able to find them in your library.